# Changing the column order of a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

Actually I am merging two files, and the final output i get after merging is what I want to re-order.

Conent of file1

**ID,Name,Class**

1,Tushar,10

2,Barkha,12

3,Vedanga,4

4,Vaanika,1

Content of file2

**ID,LastN,Section**

1,Gupta,A

2,Gupta,B

3,Gupta,C

4,Gupta,D

***merged file***

**ID,Name,Class,LastN,Section**

1,Tushar,10,Gupta,A

2,Barkha,12,Gupta,B

3,Vedanga,4,Gupta,C

4,Vaanika,1,Gupta,D

I want to re-arrange some columns of the above as

**ID,Name,LastN,Class,Section**

1,Tushar,Gupta,10,A

2,Barkha,Gupta,12,B

3,Vedanga,Gupta,4,C

4,Vaanika,Gupta,1,D

Check the change in the order of the column in which they appear.

Is there a way it can be done, Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I am using.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def mergeFiles():
    a = pd.read_csv("C:/tushar/Python/file1.txt")
    b = pd.read_csv("C:/tushar/Python/file2.txt")

    #print(a)
    #print(b)

    merged = a.merge(b, on='ID')
    #print(merged)
    merged.to_csv("C:/tushar/Python/output1.csv", index=False)

def writeFiles():
    with open('C:/tushar/Python/output1.csv') as fi, open('C:/tushar/Python/output2.csv', 'wb') as fo:
        cr = csv.reader(fi)
        cw = csv.writer(fo)

        for ln in cr:
            lo = [ln[0], ln[1], ln[3], ln[2], ln[4]]
            cw.writerow(lo)
        print(cw)

def main():
    mergeFiles()
    writeFiles()

main()
```

Comment: give us some starter code to show us you at least tried.

Comment: done, just for the sake of confidentiality, I am using dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

csv files are read as lists so simply rearrange the list and write it back out:

```
import csv

#input: ID,Name,Class,LastN,Section
#output: ID,Name,LastN,Class,Section

with open('xx.csv') as fi, open('x2.csv', 'wb') as fo:
    cr = csv.reader(fi)
    cw = csv.writer(fo)
    for ln in cr:
        lo = [ln[0], ln[1], ln[3], ln[2], ln[4]]
        cw.writerow(lo)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I am still not getting what I want.

Comment: what are you asking for then - your posted code and what i show are doing what you asked - what is missing?